# How to write a function which repeats a block of code, without calling the same function

Tags: java, function, minesweeper

I'm programming Minesweeper in Java for a school project. I have a piece of code which works, but just very slow. The function should open cells which are beside an empty cell (the function in regular Minesweeper to open near cells). The problem is, that this function has to open itself to work. I hope someone can help me.

```js
void floodFill() {
        revealed = true; // Function is started and cell is revealed
        // This block has to play through for every empty field
        if (nr == 0) { //Checks if empty cell
            if (revealed) { //Checks if already opened, if not, it will just draw it
                for (int xoff = -1; xoff <= 1; xoff++) { //Checks surroundings
                    int celli = i + xoff;
                    if (celli < 0 || celli >= row)
                        continue;
                    for (int yoff = -1; yoff <= 1; yoff++) { //Checks surroundings
                        int cellj = j + yoff;
                        if (cellj < 0 || cellj >= col)
                            continue;
                        if (!grid[celli][cellj].revealed) {
                            grid[celli][cellj].revealed = true;
                            //Here it should play the block through with the new values
                            //Should be like "grid[celli][cellj].floodFill();",
                            //but should not open the function again
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        draw(); //Draws everything in a frame
    }
```

Would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can call the same method each time you reveal an empty tile and make your method recursively. You shouldn't have runtime problems since (correct me if I'm wrong) your T(n) would be less than O(3^n) and the amount of tiles (probably) isn't too much.